# Tikz externalize not working on Tectonic despite shell-escape enabling

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, xetex, externalize, tectonic

While trying to compile some graphs with PgfPlots I incurred in the out-of-memory error in Tectonic. I therefore looked around for solution and *Tikz externalization* presented itself as a solution. Unfortunately such paradigm requires to operate tex engines with the flag *--shell-escape* or equivalent. Even though the philosophy of Tectonic is against the use of this paradigm, it was implemented recently to allow for the use of certain packages. That being said, the externalization is not working. Indeed, by running `tectonic --keep-logs -Z shell-escape  exampl.tex` I incur in the following error:

```
note: running shell command: `xelatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "exampl-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{exampl}\input{exampl}"`
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
warning: command exited with error code 1
error: failed to execute the shell-escape command "xelatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "exampl-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{exampl}\input{exampl}"": execution of the request failed
error: exampl.tex:26: Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'xelatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "exampl-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{exampl}\input{exampl}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'exampl-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:.bmp:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'exampl-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

My tex file contains the following entries regarding Tikz and Pgfplots:

```
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
```

By excluding the more memory intensive graphs, I can compile the file by commenting out the `\tikzexternalize` entry. When I include it the engine produces the error reported above instead. The log file doesn't contain any further information.

Does anybody have an idea what is happening and how I could fix it?

Thank you for your time.

As kindly pointed out I haven't thought of putting some usable code that could be used to recreate the bug. Here:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize


\title{Title}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot[] coordinates{
                (-1,1)
                (1,1)
            }; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code works when `\tikzexternalize` is commented out.

Comment: Since you're not showing any code that triggers the problem, it's going to be difficult to help. Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Thank you @Miyase , I hope the example I provided is minimal enough.